# jquery ui draggable - clone does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm using jquery 1.8.3 and jquery-ui-1.9.1.  In the code below, I have 3 choices for the user. Depending upon their choice, 5 images are displayed.  One of these images can then be dragged into the preview window.  If the user changes his/her mind, they can drag another image onto the preview window, which will replace the first one.  What does not work now is using the "clone" helper option.  If I drag an image onto the preview window it completely disappears.  Once I take the "clone" option out, the image drops in fine, but I also want it to stay in its original spot. I have checked all the other similar questions on the board, but none works for me.  I've tested in both FF and IE latest versions.

Here is the first bit of code displaying the 3 options:

```
<div id="choices">
    <ul>
        <li id="birthdaychoice"><a href="#">Birthday</a></li>
       <li id="plainchoice"><a href="#">Plain</a></li>
      <li id="flowerschoice"><a href="#">Flowers</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Next comes the code for each of the choices, displaying the correct set of images.  I've only put one of the choices below for brevity's sake.

```
<div id="makeMeDraggable">
    <div id="birthday">
        <ul>
          <li><img src="images/stationery/tooltips/christmastooltip.png" width="68" height="80" alt="Slide 1" /></li>
           <li><img src="images/stationery/tooltips/eastertooltip.png" width="68" height="80" alt="Slide 2" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/stationery/tooltips/footballtooltip.png" width="68" height="80" alt="Slide 3" /></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
```

And now here is the js code:

```
$("#birthday li").draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  containment: '#preview',
  cursor: 'move',
  appendTo: 'body'
});


$("#preview").droppable({
   accept: '.draggable',
   activeClass: "custom-state-active",
   drop: function( event, ui ) {
     $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());
           //    $item.appendTo("#preview");
           //   $(ui.draggable).attr('src','image/10.jpg');
    }
        });
```

Any idea how to remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `clone(true)` to clone element with data and events. See also [the API doc](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) for more info.